# DVI To HDTV image 

Tags: amd-radeon, hdtv

Im working with a ATI Radeon HD2400, using an dvi-hdmi cable ..to connect my pc with my tv.. After sometime my pc, stopped recognising my tv. Saying : Another display not detected.. Im using win7 ... and a dvi - hdmi cable (pc to tv).. I am using Catalyst 11.11

Edited*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. I need some clarification here - you are working with a single ATI Radeon HD2400 correct?  From there, you have a Samsung 40inch TV and you note 1xHDMI and 1xUSB.  Not sure why you note the USB, but I am assuming you have it hooked up using the HDMI connection?  And then from there you have one more display or display adapter?  I am not familiar with any ATI "display" only adapters...??

So... IF you are referring to a display that is not recognizing that you want to extend your desktop across, can you tell me what OS you are using and also what port on the card you are using for this second display?  If I don't have it correctly, please break down the situation a little more clearly.

Going on the idea I DO have it right aside from the info I asked for, you should make sure you have the newest Catalyst suite installed on your system and that the driver is properly showing in Device Manager.  Make sure and check the version there as well, I am pretty sure their latest is 11.11 but ATI updates REGULARLY so I'd always advise checking the AMD site for new ones.  Make sure your connections are good of course and maybe try using the other display as a single monitor just to make sure everything works correctly and post your reulsts nad that info if you keep having issues.

Comment: Im working with a ATI Radeon HD2400, using an dvi-hdmi cable ..to connect my pc with my tv..

After sometime my pc, stopped recognising my tv.

Saying : Another display not detected..

Im using win7 ... and a dvi - hdmi cable (pc to tv)..
I am using Catalyst 11.11.